# MySQL Sum, Count or Join?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
Country, City, 
COUNT(City) As Total, 
SUM(completion_status IN ('Started', 'Complete')) AS Total_Resp
FROM trespondent 
WHERE completion_status <> 'New' 
GROUP BY Country, City 
ORDER BY Counntry, City
```

This brings back what I would expect, which is a list of Cities with the Counts in each, no problem at all

```
Country     City     Total     Total_Resp
UK          London   150       23
UK          Leeds    150       83
France      Paris    235       99
France      Lyon     421       222
```

What I am trying to do is bring back the Total for the Countries as a whole as well, so UK and France as a whole would look like this:

```
Country     City     Total_Country   Total_city   Total_Resp
UK          London   300                150       23
UK          Leeds    300                150       83
France      Paris    656                235       99
France      Lyon     656                421       222
```

Now, I've tried simply adding to the SQL statement

```
COUNT(Country) As Total_Country
SUM(Country) As Total_Country
```

But both bring back the same count as City, I'm now thinking this is not possible without the use of JOIN.  Can anyone advise?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `COUNT(Country) As Total_Country
SUM(Country) As Total_Country` - You need to use different aliases.

Comment: Cheers Fred-ii- they've not gone in at the same time for the reason you give.....I've tried them seperately, thanks though.

Comment: You're welcome. You've some good answers below, *cheers*

Comment: Try [WITH ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery for this:

```sql
SELECT t1.Country, t1.City, 
       (SELECT COUNT(t2.Country)
        FROM trespondent AS t2
        WHERE t2.Country = t1.Country) AS Total_Country,
        COUNT(t1.City) As Total_city, 
       SUM(t1.completion_status IN ('Started', 'Complete')) AS Total_Resp
FROM trespondent AS t1
WHERE t1.completion_status <> 'New' 
GROUP BY t1.Country, t1.City 
ORDER BY t1.Country, t1.City
```

Comment: 'WHERE t2.Country = t1.Country) AS Total_Country' - I think that needs a comma after that - as when I added that back in this gives me exactly what I need - brilliant!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, you would just use window functions.  In MySQL, there are several approaches.

```
SELECT r.Country, r.City, rr.Total_Country, COUNT(r.City) As Total, 
       SUM(r.completion_status IN ('Started', 'Complete')) AS Total_Resp
FROM trespondent r JOIN
     (SELECT r2.Country, COUNT(*) as Total_Country
      FROM trespondent r2
      WHERE r2.completion_status <> 'New' 
      GROUP BY r2.Country
     ) rr
     ON r.Country = rr.Country
WHERE r.completion_status <> 'New' 
GROUP BY r.Country, r.City, rr.Total_Country
ORDER BY r.Country, r.City;
```

Although you can approach this in other ways (such as a correlated subquery), I suspect you might want other values summarized at the country level as well.  These are easier to add with a subquery.  For instance, you can readily add the number of responders in the country as well.

Comment: Many thanks Gordon, appreciated.  Much performance difference between your approach and Giorgos's below I wonder?

Comment: @Homer_J . . . You can test each for performance.  Because you have no filters that reduce the number of returned rows, I would expect this to be faster.  Correlated subqueries can be fast (even faster), but they really shine when filters reduce the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE`. For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(CASE WHEN Country = 'France' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalFrance
```